# How to use multiple where conditions in pynamodb ORM

Tags: python, orm, amazon-dynamodb

I am using PynamoDB and Flask, and I want to query objects with a query like `field1=value1 and field2=value2`.

Here `field1` and `field2` are of type `NumberAttribute()`.

```
from pynamodb.models import Model
from pynamodb.attributes import UnicodeAttribute, NumberAttribute,UTCDateTimeAttribute

class SMSQuota(Model):
    id = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    user_id = NumberAttribute(null=True)
    sms_quota = NumberAttribute()
    validity_date = UTCDateTimeAttribute(null=True)
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'SMSQuota'
        region = 'us-west-2'
        write_capacity_units = 1
        read_capacity_units = 1
```

How can this be done in PynamoDB ORM?

Items = SMSQuota.query( ?? , filter_condition  = ?? )

Answer (score 1):

I had been trying the query similar to what is shown in the docs as @Delvidi mentioned, but it kept on throwing a `TypeError`.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'UnicodeAttribute'
```

The example shows: `SomeModel.field1 == 'value1' & SomeModel.field2 == 'value2'`

But if you look further in the docs at the [Conditional Expressions](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conditional.html#condition-expressions), it shows that a parens is necessary.  So...

```
results = MyModel.query(user, (MyModel.field1 == True) & (MyModel.field2 == "a"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue here and I believe the query you need is similar to this:

```
# id must be the has_key as you wrote in your model
items = SMSQuota.query(id, filter_condition=((SMSQuota.field1==value1) & (SMSQuota.field2==value2))
```

I had to make sure I used parenthesis correctly to avoid any "TypeError: unsupported operand type"

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can query your model combining query terms, like this:

```
SomeModel.field1 == 'value1' & SomeModel.field2 == 'value2'
```

More help on how to work with pynamodb here: http://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html